# Why null is getting compared with null in the join condition in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, null

It's a simple self join I am trying to do on below data

[image: Input Data]

and the O/P I am getting after running following query (This is not the complete output, just showing the null part of it)

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.Length1, b.* 
from [dbo].[Combine] a 
  left join [dbo].[Combine] b on a.col1 =b.col1
```

[image: part of Output]

Why Null is getting compared and coming 9 times?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the column `col1` for these rows has a literal string value of ‘NULL’ and not a missing value null indicator? - [sqlraptor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/149630/sqlraptor)

You can test by adding the conditions and comparing the output of the queries:

```
WHERE a.col1 = 'NULL'

WHERE a.col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul. It was a string 'NULL'.

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons.